# SSRS vs. any other Technology for integrating to current Web Application

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, reporting, ssrs-2008

I am here to get the opinion on Reporting Services vs any other technology suitable for Reports. 
Current Environment - BIDS 2005, SQL Server 2005, C# 3.5, VS2008.

requirement - 
My Client needs to integrate the huge reports into current existing Web Application.
1) The Technology should be able to handle large number of users.
2) All clients are external, so they can review the reports anytime.
3) Caching of parameters and the report should be possible.
4) The Report Viewer is better or SOAP API is better considering Reporting Services.
5) Charts can be used - good Visualization.

All opinions are welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The most honest answer you're going to get is "it depends." What is your familiarity with with SQL Server Reporting Services? What's your familiarity with the other tools? Do you have a DBA who is familiar with SSRS? There are way too many factors that play into this to give you a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly I'm biased but I think you should look at [Windward Reports](http://www.windwardreports.com/). It's a lot easier and faster than SSRS and you design the report in Word, Excel, or PowerPoint so you can do a lot more.